# What is Benchmark error code 4 in Hyperledger Caliper

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-caliper

> error: [FabricCAClientService.js]: Failed to enroll admin, error:%o message=Could not parse enrollment response [Client sent an HTTP request to an HTTPS server.
>   ] as JSON due to error [SyntaxError: Unexpected token C in JSON at position 0], stack=Error: Could not parse enrollment response [Client sent an HTTP request to an HTTPS server.
>   ] as JSON due to error [SyntaxError: Unexpected token C in JSON at position 0]
>       at IncomingMessage.response.on (F:\SE\3rd_Year\FYP\Blockchain\hyperledger-template\hyperledger-caliper\node_modules\fabric-client\node_modules\fabric-ca-client\lib\FabricCAClient.js:475:21)
>       at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:203:15)
>       at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1145:12)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
>   2020.06.06-23:24:43.152 error [caliper] [caliper-engine]        Error while performing "init" step: Error: Couldn't enroll Patient's registrar or set it as user context: Could not parse enrollment response [Client sent an HTTP request to an HTTPS server.
>   ] as JSON due to error [SyntaxError: Unexpected token C in JSON at position 0]
>   2020.06.06-23:24:43.153 info  [caliper] [caliper-engine]        Executed "init" step in 0.527 seconds
>   2020.06.06-23:24:43.153 info  [caliper] [caliper-engine]        Network configuration attribute "caliper.command.end" is not present, skipping end command
>   2020.06.06-23:24:43.154 error [caliper] [cli-launch-master]     Benchmark failed with error code 4

This is the output of the bash. I have no idea what causes this. My network has 3 organizations with 2 peers each and one orderer. And I have edited the fabic-node.yaml file to match the requirements.
IF anyone has any suggestions  on what to do im all ears. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, error code 4 is when you try to initialize connection with blockchain (SUT) but failed, error code 5 is when you fail to install smart contract and error code 6 is for other errors (e.g configuration)